# A regex for string with tags

Tags: java, regex

I need help. I don't know how to make pattern.

```
String text ="<h1 align=\"center\">Как поймать льва?</h1>\n <h2 align=\"right\">Метод перебора</h2>";
```

I have a string and I have to make a pattern to split all tags. So result must be :

```
<h1> align="right" </h1> <h2> align="center" </h2>
```

I am doing a project for a company. I tried to find something in their blog about this problem, but couldn't

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(<)[^\b\"](>)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
while(matcher.find())
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
```

So I tried this one, but the result is always false

Comment: [There are much better tools available for parsing html than regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/6073886)

Comment: I'm not sure why you're linking to that particular *corporate* (as in: non-technical) blog. It makes your question look like a veiled SEO attempt or, worse, spam.

Comment: I need only regex, a usual tool for strings

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca but maybe you know the answer to my question? How to split tags using regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to see `<h1>` in your result but there isn't this tag alone in your original input. You have `<h1` and `</h1>`. As far as I can tell, you need an extra check on your result.

```
    String text = "<h1 align=\"center\">Как поймать льва?</h1>\n <h2 align=\"right\">Метод перебора</h2>";
    String regex = "(?<=\\<)(.*?)(?=\\>)";
    
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
            
    while(matcher.find())
    {               
        if(matcher.group().contains("="))
        {
            String tag = matcher.group().substring(0,2);                
            System.out.println("<" + tag + ">" + matcher.group().substring(2, matcher.group().length()) + " </" + tag + ">");
        }           
    }
```

Result:

```
<h1> align="center" </h1>
<h2> align="right" </h2>
```